# Errors on new project build - no code changed

Tags: c++, macos, qt, osx-mountain-lion

I installed 4.8.4 QT library on Mountain Lion.
I then installed QT Creator.

I had problems compiling due to no CMD tools/ Xcode.

I then installed those and now when running the application, I get the following errors.

[image: ERRORS!]

It's worth mentioning that this is a new project, I've changed no code and purely just tried to run it and this is the result.

Any ideas what's going on?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem was that I was selecting a 32 bit compiler on a 64 bit machine. As simple as that!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you had installed 64 bit Qt libraries on a 32 bit machine.

Comment: Before seeing this, I realised I was running a 32 bit compiler on a 64 bit machine. Close enough!